Azure signalr group exists without connections?
How can REST GET /api/v1/hubs/{hub}/groups/{group} return 200 OK if service live metrics in azure portal show 0 client connections?

use https://<instance-name>.service.signalr.net/api/v1/hubs/<hub-name>/groups/<group-name> to Broadcast to a group

There  is no  client applications actively trying to connect to the Azure SignalR Service.The Azure SignalR Service creates application server and client connections. By default, each application server starts with five initial connections per hub, and each client has one client connection.
For example, assume that you have two application servers and you define five hubs in code. The server connection count is 50: (2 app servers * 5 hubs * 5 connections per hub).The connection count shown in the Azure portal includes server, client, diagnostic, and live trace connections.

Client connection: Connects Azure SignalR Service and the client app.

From this doc:
GET /api/v1/hubs/myHub/groups/myGroup
Host:https://<instance-name>.service.signalr.net
Authorization: Bearer <your_token_here>

200 Success

This indicates the number of client connections in the specified group. The GET method does not interact with clients to retrieve data.

From this doc,

The method Broadcast sends a message to the clients, which connects with the client to send the message.  The client, the client connection connects to the Azure SignalR Service and the client app/code/API. connection connects to the Azure SignalR Service and the client app/code/API.
I referred to this doc to connect to a client using the ClientHandler class.
 public class ClientHandler
 {
     private readonly HubConnection _connection;

     public ClientHandler(string connectionString, string hubName, string userId)
     {
         var serviceUtils = new ServiceUtils(connectionString);

         var url = GetClientUrl(serviceUtils.Endpoint, hubName);

         _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl(url, option =>
             {
                 option.AccessTokenProvider = () =>
                 {
                     return Task.FromResult(serviceUtils.GenerateAccessToken(url, userId));
                 };
             }).Build();

         _connection.On<string, string>("SendMessage",
             (string server, string message) =>
             {
                 Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString()}] Received message from server {server}: {message}");
             });
     }

     public async Task StartAsync()
     {
         await _connection.StartAsync();
     }

     public async Task DisposeAsync()
     {
         await _connection.DisposeAsync();
     }

     private string GetClientUrl(string endpoint, string hubName)
     {
         return $"{endpoint}/client/?hub={hubName}";
     }
 }



